# How would you make a wireframe in OpenGl ES (GLESv2)

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying to make a wireframe for a shader and object, but I'm not sure how you would do it in OpenGL ES (2.0) because you cannot use the glPolygonMode function in it. In other words, it has been removed.

Comment: "*In other words, it has been deprecated.*" No, it wasn't. "Deprecated" means "available, but subject to later removal". `glPolygonMode` was *never* part of OpenGL ES 2.0, or any version of ES.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for correcting me. Would you know how to make a wireframe in GLES?

Comment: You have to use line primitives, e.g. GL_LINES

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out. It required the gl polygon offset and lines pretty much :)